# Right way to remove a leading character

Tags: javascript, regex

Im pretty new to regex and am trying to remove a leading underscore '_' from any string.

```
replace(/^[_]+/, "")
```

This works, but I want to be sure: Is this the correct way to do it?

As I can't find a lot about this special problem around the web, I'm asking about it here.

Comment: no need of character class `replace(/^_+/, "")`

Comment: If you want to remove only one `_` you should also remove the `+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be enough:

`replace(/^_/, '');`

Answer (score 1):

That works however, it will remove 1-n number of leading underscores. For example, _x becomes x but __x becomes x as well; all the way to n number of leading underscores. If you only want to remove the first leading underscore use the following:

```
some_string.replace(/^_{1}/, '');
```

This is using a quantifier to match only 1. Note that this quantifier is not greedy, + quantifier is one or more and greedy. You could also use your original code with the non-greedy modifier ? as follows:

```
some_string.replace(/^[_]+?/, '');
```

One last note, you don't need to use the character class operator, [...], in this case. It's not wrong or bad form, just unnecessary.